# MongoDB - How can I check if some element in an array meets a condition with another element of an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following objects in my Java APP:

```
[
  {
    "from" : "11/12/2020",
    "to" : "12/12/2019"
  },
  {
    "from" : "13/12/2020",
    "to" : "14/12/2020
  }
]
```

and in my DB I have the following objects:

```
[
  {
    "from" : "01/12/2020",
    "to" : "14/12/2019"
  },
  {
    "from" : "20/12/2020",
    "to" : "30/12/2020
  }
]
```

What query can I write to check if any of the dates `from` or `to` from any object in my first Java APP will be gte or lte than any of the `from` or `to` values from my DB objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate over all DB entries and compare them to your object.
If you are using JPA Repositories to communicate with your DB, you can do that like this:

```
List<Entry> matches = dataRepository.findAll().stream().filter(dbEntry -> dbEntry.equals(myEntry)).collect(Collectors.asList());
```

The ArrayList will now contain all of your matches from the Database.